# Groovy and Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, groovy, sublimetext2

I am on a Mac OS X system and use Sublime Text 2 for Groovy development. When I build my file I get

```
/Users/it.dev/groovy-2.1.8/bin/groovy: line 31: dirname: command not found
/Users/it.dev/groovy-2.1.8/bin/groovy: line 33: /startGroovy: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I have placed the path to groovy on my `/etc/launched.conf` file as follows

```
setenv GROOVY_HOME /Users/it.dev/groovy-2.1.8
setenv PATH $PATH:$GROOVY_HOME/bin
```

from the command line groovy works fine. What am I doing wrong ?

Edited -

The above error disappears after correcting the `PATH` variable. Still get this error.

```
/Users/it.dev/groovy-2.1.8/bin/groovy: line 31: dirname: command not found
/Users/it.dev/groovy-2.1.8/bin/groovy: line 33: /startGroovy: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621201/using-groovy-with-sublime-text

Comment: yes.That has been deleted.

Comment: Works for Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 2):

step 1. add a file "${Sublime-Package}/User/groovy.sublime-build" to the APPLICATION FLODER.

step 2. edit the "groovy.sublime-build" like this

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/groovy/bin/groovy", "$file"]
}
```

of course, '/usr/local/groovy' is my GROOVY_HOME, you have to use your GROOVY_HOME

step 2. restart your "sublime text 2"

step 3. open a groovy script file.

step 4. MENU -> tools -> build system -> check the "groovy"

step 5. MENU -> tools -> build (CMD + B)

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers already describe the overall process, here is a complete configuration which works on OSX:

```
{
"cmd": ["groovy","$file"],
"file_regex": "[ ]*at .+[(](.+):([0-9]+)[)]",
"selector": "source.groovy",
"path": "/Path/to/your/groovy/installation:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin"
}
```

Note: The first part of the "path" entry is the folder in which the groovy binary is located (fill in the location of groovy on your computer). The rest of the entries are required for other commands used by sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

I run groovy scripts on OSX (10.8) from sublime-text 2 using the following sublime build file.

```
{
    "cmd": ["groovy","$file"],
    "selector": "source.groovy",

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "cmd.exe"
    }

}
```

The comments on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kdabir/2203530) should help for PATH and other issues.

Comment: I did this. The new is given in the EDIT portion of the question. I use the build file from your question and restarted Sublime Text 2.

Comment: What version groovy ? And your PATH configuration please ?

Comment: groovy 2.1.6. To add groovy in PATH for a application please see this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x

Comment: I have did this. It can find groovy but not startGroovy ? What can the problem  be ?